# WinRM not returning client information - quickconfig not working

Tags: powershell, winrm

I am trying to change settings on WinRM however I keep getting an error.

I have read many articles across the web about it but I cannot get any of the suggested fixes to work

When I try to get the winRM quickconfig, which is the common suggested fix, to work I get this:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> winrm qc
WinRM service is already running on this machine.
WSManFault
    Message = The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the request. Verify that the service on the dest
ination is running and is accepting requests. Consult the logs and documentation for the WS-Management service running o
n the destination, most commonly IIS or WinRM. If the destination is the WinRM service, run the following command on the
 destination to analyze and configure the WinRM service: "winrm quickconfig".

Error number:  -2144108526 0x80338012
The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the request. Verify that the service on the destination is run
ning and is accepting requests. Consult the logs and documentation for the WS-Management service running on the destinat
ion, most commonly IIS or WinRM. If the destination is the WinRM service, run the following command on the destination t
o analyze and configure the WinRM service: "winrm quickconfig".
```

The service is running and the firewall rules are all set correctly.

I get the same error regardless of what I'm trying to achieve.

E.G.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> winrm get winrm/config
WSManFault
    Message = The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the request. Verify that the service on the dest
ination is running and is accepting requests. Consult the logs and documentation for the WS-Management service running o
n the destination, most commonly IIS or WinRM. If the destination is the WinRM service, run the following command on the
 destination to analyze and configure the WinRM service: "winrm quickconfig".

Error number:  -2144108526 0x80338012
The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the request. Verify that the service on the destination is run
ning and is accepting requests. Consult the logs and documentation for the WS-Management service running on the destinat
ion, most commonly IIS or WinRM. If the destination is the WinRM service, run the following command on the destination t
o analyze and configure the WinRM service: "winrm quickconfig".

PS C:\Windows\system32> winrm enumerate winrm/config/listener
WSManFault
    Message = The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the request. Verify that the service on the dest
ination is running and is accepting requests. Consult the logs and documentation for the WS-Management service running o
n the destination, most commonly IIS or WinRM. If the destination is the WinRM service, run the following command on the
 destination to analyze and configure the WinRM service: "winrm quickconfig".

Error number:  -2144108526 0x80338012
The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the request. Verify that the service on the destination is run
ning and is accepting requests. Consult the logs and documentation for the WS-Management service running on the destinat
ion, most commonly IIS or WinRM. If the destination is the WinRM service, run the following command on the destination t
o analyze and configure the WinRM service: "winrm quickconfig".
```

I have tried stopping and restarting the Windows Remote Management service in the local Services.
Also tried changing the settings in the Group Policy on the machine. All to no avail.
Checked the expanded analysis logs in the event viewer, no further clues there, it just shows the error above.

Is there anyway to uninstall and reinstall ? I cannot find any info on that, online to configure.  I don't seem to be able to get back to the initial setup like this (example from another machine)

```
PS P:\> winrm qc
WinRM is not set up to receive requests on this machine.
The following changes must be made:

Start the WinRM service.
Set the WinRM service type to delayed auto start.

Make these changes [y/n]? n
```

I am current using :
Windows 2008 R2 SP1
Powershell 5.1
TFS 2017 is also installed on the server.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Do you have any proxies set up?  Check `NETSH WINHTTP SHOW PROXY`

Comment: @DarkLite1 That's not a configuration but an issue with DNS.

Comment: Do you perhaps have a GPO `“Allow automatic configuration of listeners”` where you have set an IPv4 filter using subnet notation (like x.x.x.x\24)? In that case this may be the solution for you: https://stackoftech.com/2015/08/02/winrm-error-2144108526-0x80338012-the-client-cannot-connect-to-the-destination-specified-in-the-request/

Answer (score 0):

You know... I could point you to some links that would help, but that always aggravates me when I'm looking for an answer. Try this from an elevated powershell prompt:

```
Set-NetConnectionProfile -NetworkCategory Private   <-- This assumes you're not in a domain
Enable-PSRemoting -SkipNetworkProfileCheck -Force  <- Yes, a bit redundant
set-service -ServiceName WinRm -StartupType Automatic
start-service winrm
```

If you continue to have trouble, add this:
winrm set winrm/config/client '@{TrustedHosts="NameOfYourComputer"}'